# Resolving In NSLOOKUP and writting it in excel

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

i have a script to resolve IP and put that in notepad . I need to put the output ( only NAME and ADDRESS ) in Excel. Any idea ?

Code :

```
 import subprocess
 import os

with open('output.txt') as i, open('nslookup.xlsx', 'w') as o:
   for line in i:
     if line.strip(): # skips empty lines
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["nslookup", line.strip()],
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        o.write('{}\n'.format(proc.communicate()[0]))

print('Done')
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample script, simply adjust it to your needs with the Output.txt file

I used `socket` for the lookup.

```
import socket
import pandas as pd

array = ['8.8.8.8','216.58.207.78', '127.0.3.3', '33', 'nana' ,'3fe']
dnsData = {'IP':'HOSTNAME'}
for ip in array:
    try:
        domain = socket.getfqdn(ip)  # Generates a tuple in the form of: ('server.example.com', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
        if (ip != domain):
            dnsData[ip] = domain
        else:
            dnsData[ip] = "Unable to resolve data"
    except socket.herror:
        print("Cannot resolve host ip", e)

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dnsData, orient = 'index')

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: should "sss" be replaced by "ip" ?

Comment: its not giving me right hostname ..should "sss" be replaced by "ip" ?

Comment: i updated in question what i am trying.. it works for me but the concern is it fails if it does not find any hostname.. can it be skiped and go to next if host not found ?

Comment: @NirmalGauda Take a look at it, tell me if it's what you wanted.

Comment: Can these '127.0.3.3', '33', 'nana' ,'3fe' be also in Excel ( instead of being displayed in terminal ) saying "unable to resolve host" ...  i processed 100 Ip's and it took long long time .. can the time to process be shorten ?

Comment: Yep it's possible, check my edit. I'm not sure if you can process it faster, since it is an internal inside sockets.

Comment: You can also check `http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2012/01/19/concurrent.futures.html` for further references on how to use futures with fqdn.

Comment: it didnt come in order .."IP" and "Hostname" came in middle after resolving couple of ip's.. can we make it faster through "subprocess ' ? Updated code in question with 'subprocess' and "nslookup"